# BASH: send SIGTSTP signal (ctrl+z)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, posix

I'm rushing against the clock for a programming assignment in which I have to run a number of instances of the same program on the same machine at the same time.
Currently, I'm starting the instances one at a time, pressing **Ctrl+z** to pause them, and then doing **'bg %#**' to resume execution in the background.

This is extremely tedious and time consuming to do every time I need to test a small change in my application, so I want to write a bash script that will start the multiple instances for me, however I don't know how to do the background switching in a script.

Can anybody please tell me how I can write a simple script that will start a long standing command, pause it, and resume it in the background?

Comment: What's the reason for pausing the command before letting it run in background?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do you want to just **start** it in the background?  For example:

```
mycommand &
```

If you want finer grained job control, you can emulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and `bg`.  <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> sends `SIGTSTP` ("tty stop") to the program, which suspends it:

```
kill -TSTP [processid]
```

And the `bg` command just sends it a `SIGCONT`:

```
kill -CONT [processid]
```

Comment: Yes!!! that meets my needs perfectly!! Thanks for the answers... I'm gonna have to go learn how to BASH fluently one of these days :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't. You put an ampersand after the command.

```
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &
```

Comment: This is not a solution if any of the commands require user interaction.