# Sending the Valgrind to the background

Tags: valgrind

I'v started a process with valgrind to find the leaks with the option `--leak-check=full` and redirecting the `stdout` and `stderr` outputs to a file. But the program seems to be running too long and now I want to send the process to the background so that I can close the terminal and check on the results at later time.

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/41959/how-to-send-jobs-to-background-without-stopping-them) I've found that by using `ctrl +z` it will suspend the process and with `bg` and `disown` commands its possible to remove the process from the terminal and run on the background

But when I try that with valgrind the process doesnot respond to the `ctrl + z` command

Is there an alternative way to send the valgrind process to background? Or am I doing the whole thing wrong?

Comment: You can start it in the background, with something like 'nohup valgrind app app_args &' (I'm not sure what valgrind does with the hup signal so you might not need it)

Comment: The thing is I can't stop the running process and start over again .. I need to switch the existing process to the background

Comment: I just had a quick look at the Valgrind source and it looks like it blocks pretty much all signals. So it looks like there's not much that you can do.

Comment: This made me curious because I have always thought `Ctrl +z` sent a `SIGSTOP` which is not meant to be blocked. But it turns out `Ctrl +z` actually sends `SIGTSTP` which is not the same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900970/bash-send-sigtstp-signal-ctrlz